# What determines whether a numerical prefix is allowable for a unit?

Tags: nouns, prefixes, measuring-units

1. The prefix *centi-* means 10<sup>-2</sup>.
   But while *centimetre* is common, I have never heard of a *centiwatt* or a *centisecond*.
2. The prefix *Mega-* means 10<sup>6</sup>. Hence *Megabytes* exist. So why do we not have *Megametres*?

Comment: Except a megabyte is not a million bytes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the unit is a [metric unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_system#Conversion_between_SI_and_legacy_units), then all [metric prefixes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_prefix#List_of_SI_prefixes) are allowable.

1. The [centiwatt](http://www.aqua-calc.com/what-is/power/centiwatt) and [centisecond](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/centisecond) are actual units of measurement, albeit rare, since one would tend to say *10 milliwatts* or *milliseconds* instead.
2. We do have *[megametres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megametre)*.

Comment: But why are some used, while others are not?

Comment: Well, seriously, who measures by millions of meters?  Also, all those terms are used, but certain ones, like _centiwatts_ are only used in highly specialized situations.  (When was the last time you worked with centiwatts?)

Comment: @drm65 Astronomers do.

Comment: @Kit: I knew that was coming - though to an astronomer, a thousand kilometers is a very slight distance.  Even astronomers say "a thousand kilometers" rather than "a megameter", in most cases.  Cf. the wikipedia page I referenced for _megameter_.

Comment: People generally use milliwatts rather than centiwatts. It's a matter of custom, and not determined by a central authority. More often than not, it depends on what unit is the proper size for a given application; this is why people often use Angstroms rather than nanometers.

Comment: @drm65 Well, sure. It's easier to conceive of a thousand familiar somethings than a million familiar somethings. A million is just overwhelming to our brain.

Comment: @Peter +1 - Very succinct, and just what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

All of the things you have mentioned exist, for exactly the reason you expect they should. If some are more common than others, it's likely because (a) only a few orders of magnitude apply to most kinds of measurement in everyday life and (b) most people are not scientists and, therefore, would rather say "a thousand kilometres" than "a megameter"... possibly because they don't even know what "mega" means.

By the by, isn't a megabyte equal to 1024 kilobytes (2^20 bytes), not 1000 kilobytes (10^6)? hah.

Comment: Nowadays, a megabyte in storage devices _is_ equal to a million bytes.  :(

Comment: According to whom? People who make hard drives? I could believe that.

Comment: Manufacturers of disk drives have hijacked the the prefix *mega* to mean 1,000,000 and we have to use mebibytes to mean 1,048,576 = 2^20 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte)

Comment: Yes, and now we are left to differentiate between the storage device GBs and GBs according to the computer.  Buy a TB hard drive, stick it in the computer, and it says you have 931 GB.

Comment: Whatever. I'll keep using "mega" as God intended, and if a Mars rover has to go down because of it, I'll still sleep easy at night.

Comment: @Pavium: _Mebibyte_ sounds utterly silly.  It hasn't caught on yet.

Comment: I don't know anyone who uses them.

Answer (score 0):

For scientists and engineers, the prefixes are defined by the International System of Units ([SI](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/prefixes.html)). The exponents increase in steps of three.

(There is a link on the SI units page to IEC units used for computers)

Older [MKS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MKS_system_of_units) units like centi are no longer preferred.

[If you see a reference in the [Jargon File](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/) to proposed units harpo- and groucho- remember, they were a joke.]